# Wix modify an existing ini file

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, ini

I was trying to modify an .ini file in Wix

If it does not exists,  the msi does not complete....

1. how do I check for this
2. I really want to modify it

Yes I looked at other stackoverflow questions/answers and on google

I was trying this...

```
      <Component Id="TestIni" Guid="*">
        <CreateFolder />

        <IniFile Id="Ini1"
                 Action="createLine"
                 Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
                 Section="Test"
                 Name="Minimal.ini"
                 Key="TestKey"
                 Value="TestValue" />

        <IniFile Id="Ini2"
                 Action="createLine"
                 Directory="WindowsFolder"
                 Section="Test"
                 Name="Minimal.ini"
                 Key="TestKey"
                 Value="WindowsFolder TestValue" />

      </Component>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `Action="addLine"` or `Action="addTag"` if you want to modify an existing value.

Comment: how do I check for if the Minimal.ini file exists?   Say I need to check to see if it is in C:\MyIni\LocationIni\

Comment: Action="addLine" or Action="addTag" will do the right thing whether the .ini file exists or not.

Comment: changed the createLine  to AddLine on both,  but still errors ,  I then noticed I had left { } around GUID , I removed those, same issue

Comment: I forget, I moved on to something else.... sorry.   It was just stopping the msi from running

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [FileSearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_filesearch.htm) element to set a property and then use this property in a condition.