# INI disappear & NeverOverwrite="yes"

Tags: wix

I have following problem  :  a new version disappears after upgrade, although I set NeverOverwrite='yes'. Could anyone help me about this issue?

```
<Feature Id="CompRef03" Title="CompRef" Level="1">
  <Component Id="INIWindowsFolder" Directory="WindowsFolder" Guid="d09921c0-1192-458f-8a3e-88889f56a013" KeyPath="yes" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes">
    <File Id="test.INI" Source="test\intest.INI"/>
  </Component>
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Problem***: Not sure exactly what has happened here. You don't set **`REINSTALLMODE=amus`**, do you? Maybe you have changed the component GUID from version 1 of your package? ([component GUIDs must remain stable between versions for reference counting to work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405100/change-my-component-guid-in-wix/1422121#1422121)). Or else the file could be uninstalled and reinstalled (should not happend when you set a file permanent, but maybe you forgot that in your first package).

***IniFile Element***: Ini files are actually not supposed to be installed as files, but as "change items" of INI value pairs. In other words you define what entries inside the file should be added, changed, removed, etc... In Wix you use the [**IniFile Element**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/inifile.html) to achieve this. All merge capabilities, rollback support and advanced ini file handling come along for free. All you need to do is to define what needs to be added or modified in the ini file during your installation. It will also be created if it is not there in the first place. [Please find more details in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026584/129130). And [here is one more link to IniFile Element usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48761048/129130).